# Getting "TypeError: u.parentNode is undefined" when calling d3.sort or d3.order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typeerror

I am trying to re-order elements in the DOM for a D3 (v4) selection. This D3 selection constantly has new elements come in, old elements get removed, and some elements stay around, and I do processing on each specific group (and do transitions and such).

At the end, I want to reorder the DOM elements so certain elements are in the foreground, but I always get "TypeError: u.parentNode is undefined" thrown by D3.

```
function updateDraw() {
    var items = getItems();
    var s = mySVG.selectAll('g').data(items, d => d.id);

    // the new items that weren't there before
    var enter = s
        .enter()
        .append('g');

    enter
        .append('circle')
        // more here

    // the items that were there before
    s.selectAll('circle')
        .transition()
        // more here

    // stuff in common with all items (newly added or still there)
    enter.merge(s)
        .selectAll('circle')
        // more here

    // the items that are no longer there
    s.exit()
        .selectAll('circle')
        // more here

    // re-order the DOM to match our new order for everything that is still there
    s.enter().merge(s).sort((a,b) => { .... });
    s.enter().merge(s).order();
}
```

Even if I remove the sort line and just try to order the elements by whatever the default order is, I get the same error. If I don't have any `sort()` or `order()` lines, then the page loads and operates perfectly fine, just with my circles in a bad order.

Any idea what's going on here? I can't just sort `items` before doing any D3 operations, because some DOM elements that already exist on the page will need to be reordered.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, my mistake is trying to re-use the enter() selection, which should only be called once to bind the data only once. Since I've saved the enter selection under `enter`,

```
enter.merge(s).sort(...)
```

works just fine.